# If someone is online in WhatsApp chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

If someone is shown to be On-line in WhatsApp inside the actual Chat we  previously had, does that mean they've opened that particular chat OR that they're simply "Online"??

Answer (score 1):

From [WhatsApp FAQ - What does last seen and online mean exactly?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971848)

> Online and last seen tell you if your contacts are online, or the last time they were using WhatsApp.
>
> - Online means that the contact has WhatsApp open and is connected to the internet. However, it does not necessarily mean the contact has read your chat.
> - Last seen refers to the last time the contact used WhatsApp.